# Rewards to users when clicking/viewing ads

Tags: ads, codenameone, reward

I intend to give rewards like coins/diamonds to users when they click on ads banner (admob banner at bottom) or view fullscreen ads in 30 seconds. Is it possible in CodenameOne?

Comment: This is a really broad question. What are you interested in and what is you specific problem? Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think it is as it's pretty much the business of this Codename One app: https://www.codenameone.com/featured-raffler.html

I'm not sure how they did it though so that's another story.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.

Comment: It is just an app and not available in US store. I actually still don't know how to do it. Chen/Shai, anyone, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As @David mentioned Raffler did exactly this but I have no idea how they did it. I think they used the [Flurry cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) but I'm not sure.